Problems with new linux kernel 6.8.0-50-generics and Wayland. Can't access to X11
I have just updated to the new 6.8.0-50-generic kernel. The first weird think I noticed is that I can't select between Wayland and X11 during the login screen (it doesn't appear the screw icon at the bottom right). When I use Chrome, Brave or Opera and I use Google Meet I can't use the blur effect because "hardware acceleration is not enabled in the browser". I've checked for that particular setting and it's enabled. When I try to force (by command bash) to use as default the X11 interface and I reboot, a black screen appears. I can use the console (with control + alt + F1) but there isn't a GUI X11 login interface. I have a GTX Nvidia 1080 GT video card. Anyone with the same problem after updating to the new kernel? I had to force to boot with the previous kernel 6.8.0-49 generic and everything is going well.
Regards!

i have the same issue but my keyboard and touchpad is stuck as well as no wifi etc , im just stuck at login page without being able to do anything , i have an asus tuf a16 advantage edition, i guess the 49 is more stable
